# JavaFX disabled element styling

Tags: css, combobox, javafx

I have a combo box with some data.

```
public class Test extends Application {
    public static final String[] items = "One Two Three".split(" ");
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final ComboBox<String> box = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(items));
        box.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: Enabled ComboBox]

If I set combo box disabled it grayed but I need to set text black. Google says what I need to set opacity to 1.0.

```
box.setDisable(true);
box.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1.0;");
```

And nothing happens. It also grayed.

[image]

Even if I set `text-fill` property to **black** it also grayed.

```
box.setDisable(true);
box.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1.0; -fx-text-fill: black;");
```

[image]

What happens? How do I change text color of disabled combo box?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `disabled` property cascades from a scene graph node to its child nodes, so all the child nodes of the combo box effectively pick up their `:disabled` CSS styles. So, for example, the `Label` displaying the selected item uses its `disabled` style, which has opacity set to 0.4.

To achieve what you want, do

```
.combo-box:disabled, .combo-box:disabled > * {
  -fx-opacity: 1.0 ;
}
```

in an external CSS file.

Comment: James, how could I do this with say ... just the column header row of a tableview? When I use this on the table .table-view:disabled, .table-view:disabled >  *  {
    -fx-opacity: 1;
} the header does not dim, but it also doesn't dim the column that has text fields in it ... but it will dim the column that has labels in it... so I'm confused.